# Not getting full duplex gigabit speed with router

Tags: networking, router, ftp, ethernet

I currently have a new Lenovo Thinkpad with a Realtek ethernet port and an Asus AC1900 router. Whenever I have just my FTP client operating, I can get nearly 1 gbps.

[Only FTP download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQpjE.png)

However, once I turn on my backup software which uploads to the cloud, the speed drops by half.

[Both FTP download and upload client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MvbC.png)

I was under the impression that full duplex gigabit meant that I could get both 1gbps up and 1gbps down simultaneously. What should I do to maximize my usage of my internet connection?

iperf result - simultaneous test between two laptops on network

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on TCP port 5001
TCP window size:  208 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.1.44, TCP port 5001
TCP window size:  208 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 192.168.1.87 port 55578 connected with 192.168.1.44 port 5001
[  5] local 192.168.1.87 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.44 port 51381
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec   988 MBytes   829 Mbits/sec
[  5]  0.0-10.0 sec  1005 MBytes   843 Mbits/sec
```

Comment: The amount bandwidth up/down depends on your ISP.

Comment: Check your ISP for the internet upload speed you are supposed to get. It is 1 Gbit down - ask them about the upload speed

Comment: My ISP plan is 1gbps symmetric

Comment: What connection type do you get from the ISP? Even though your Ethernet connection from computer to the modem / router / media converter is full-duplex, that doesn't mean the connection _from_ the device to ISP is too...

Comment: @user1686 Not too many details on the ISP webpage - all I know is that there is 940 mbps up/940 mbps down over a fibre optic connection. The ISP's traffic management policy states that it does not manage or slow down the connection to any customers.

Comment: Run http://dslreports.com/speedtest to check your bufferbloat grade. If your grade is less than an A, edit your question to include a link to your results page. It could be that your router mismanages its packet queues in the face of congestion. For that matter it may be that your router doesn't have the CPU horsepower to do 1Gbps NAT in both directions as the same time. What speed do you get if you plug your Thinkpad directly into the ONT?

Comment: @Spiff - I got an A for bufferbloat, A+ for quality and A+ overall. I have plugged the laptop directly into the wall before - similar behaviour as when I plug it into the router. I can get 1gbps download or upload in isolation, but when both are occurring simultaneously, it only adds up to 1gbps. For DSLreports, it shows down as about 600mbps and up around 950mbps - however it's >900mbps on speedtest for both. I also updated the initial post with result from iperf which a member on a different site suggested

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that symmetric bandwidth on a full duplex connection will give you the ability to have 1Gbps up and down. However, that doesn't mean you will get 1Gbps to all destinations. While it is highly probable that your cloud backup provider has a multi-gigabit connection to the Internet, that doesn't mean they will provide 1Gbps connections to their clients. They might be limiting incoming connections, as to not saturate their bandwidth and allow more people to connect. Other possibilities might be compression or encryption is slowing down the transfer. Additionally, any of the network hops in between you and the backup provider can be causing the limitation.

You can talk to your cloud backup provider's support to see if they can do provide any assistance.

Comment: That may be true, but why would it affect the _other_ download stream which had been running at 1 Gbps until that point?

Comment: Sorry I should have included a third screenshot. The cloud provider is Google. When I disable FTP and am just uploading to Google, I can get up to 900 mbps+. However, once I turn FTP on, then I get the second screenshot where it's 450 mbps up and 450 mbps down ish.